# Proposal to add a "Circlejerk" badge

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request, fun

I propose that when a group of people upvote each other repeatedly, they get awarded the "Circlejerk" badge.

Comment: I would rather apply the banhammer.

Comment: Sometimes people upvote one another for legitimate reasons. I propose that in such situations, the "Circlejerk" badge is given. This of course wouldn't replace banning for those who are trying to game the system.

Comment: Maybe something like a "community" badge?

Comment: @Borgleader you mean gang bang hammer.

Comment: Alright, I laughed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/349538)

Comment: This incourages serial voting

Answer (score 17):

> a group of people upvote each other repeatedly

So... what reason allows this to be within our standards? What this means that there is now a badge that supports:

- "Gang" voting
- Serial Upvoting
- Sockpuppet Upvoting
- Other types of illegal group upvoting

We already have badges for voting and upvoting already. What good does this do? Groups of people will dive for the badge, give themselves lots of rep they only received because of the badge. And serial upvoters will have a reason to avoid suspension. This will only create chaos and will bring trouble-makers to Stack Exchange.

And anyway, the proposed badge name is "Circlejerk". You are right. Those people are in their little circles/groups and are *jerks*. This behavior will never be tolerated and in response, we give them a gift or two: The Amazing Suspension and The Destruction of the Violator's Account(s). So don't even think about this type of serial upvoting to become legal at all.

Comment: People really don't have a sense of humor on SE, eh?